# How to build a relationship between values?

Tags: python, opencv

I have the following code which gives coordinates of corners. However, it gives only the coordinates.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = 'CornerDetectionImage.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(filename)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gray = np.float32(gray)
dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray, 2, 3, 0.04)

# Threshold for an optimal value, it may vary depending on the image.
img[dst>0.01*dst.max()] = [0, 0, 255]
cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', img)

coord = np.where(np.all(img == (0, 0, 255), axis=-1))

lol = zip(coord[0], coord[1])
print(lol)
print ("")

x = np.array(lol, dtype="int")
print (x)

filename1 = open("CoordinatesForCornerDetectionImage.txt", "w")
filename1.write(str(lol))
filename1.close()

filename2 = open("CoordinatesNpArray.txt", "w")
filename2.write(str(x))
filename2.close()

plt.scatter(coord[0], coord[1])
plt.show()
```

The image that I have used is attached below,

[image: CornerDetectionImage]

I dont know whether you can see it or not, the detected corners are colored in red.
[image: DetectedCorners]

I have marked A-U the order of the detected corners. Below is the result(Coordinates).

```
[(27, 37), (27, 38), (27, 163), (27, 164), (27, 266), (27, 267), (27, 356), (27, 357), (27, 448), (27, 449), (27, 528), (27, 529), (28, 37), (28, 38), (28, 163), (28, 164), (28, 266), (28, 267), (28, 356), (28, 357), (28, 448), (28, 449), (28, 528), (28, 529), (51, 163), (51, 164), (51, 266), (51, 267), (51, 356), (51, 357), (51, 448), (51, 449), (52, 61), (52, 62), (52, 163), (52, 164), (52, 266), (52, 267), (52, 280), (52, 305), (52, 306), (52, 356), (52, 357), (52, 448), (52, 449), (52, 504), (52, 505), (53, 61), (53, 62), (53, 280), (53, 281), (53, 305), (53, 306), (53, 504), (53, 505), (355, 61), (355, 62), (355, 280), (355, 281), (355, 305), (355, 306), (355, 504), (355, 505), (356, 61), (356, 62), (356, 280), (356, 281), (356, 305), (356, 306), (356, 504), (356, 505), (380, 37), (380, 38), (380, 528), (380, 529), (381, 37), (381, 38), (381, 528), (381, 529)]
```

I am unable to understand the relationship with these coordinates. What I do want to know is to understand that a point with its coordinates is conencted with which other coordinate.

For example,

How is A is connected to B and T?
How is B is connected to A and H?
How is C is connected to I and D?

How can I build this relation?

Comment: check this https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/

Comment: @Ni. the link is about if you have the relation with coordinates. But i need to know how to make the relation

Answer (score 1):

This is only a quick suggestion (not in any way a definite answer).

You could try iterating over lines between your detected corners with OpenCV `LineIterator` (http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#lineiterator) and check that near every pixel on this line you have both white and black pixels (take a small window around each pixel).

This could work on the image you used but it is probably too naïve to work on more complicated images.